Finding the "true" code version of AWS Lambda runtime
The Issue
We ran into a situation where an AWS lambda runtime version update appears to be causing issues with our code.
This works (nodejs 18.v24; also .v26 works):

This does not work (nodejs 18.v28):

However, those version numbers do not correspond to actual Node versions that I can find. On the Node site, the latest version of 18 is 18.20.2 (as of this writing).

The Question
How do I find the actual Node version behind the AWS version number so I can compare differences between v.26 and v.28 to try to determine what update might be causing issues with our code?

does anyone know the ARN of the nodejs18.v26?

The AWS CLI doesn't provide a means for converting a lambda ARN or a lambda runtime ARN into a corresponding Node.js version.
If you want this information just report it to CloudWatch via console.log(process.version), and then inspect the log for a test run.
For example:
export const handler = async (event) => {
  console.log('NODE_VERSION', process.version)
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: process.version,
  };
  return response;
};

Produces logs like:
INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:20.v22   Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2::runtime:b41f958332022b46328145bcd27dce02539c950ccbf6fde05884f8106362b755

2024-05-07T18:44:28.717Z    47f2299a-daec-4586-b97f-fd7c0ebf66b4    INFO    NODE_VERSION v20.12.0


The Lambda runtime version does not correlate to the Node.js minor version, so for example the runtime version "nodejs 18.v24" does not mean it should be using Node.js version 18.24.x, rather it's the 24th time aws has updated the nodejs18 runtime.
The issue is likely being caused by a dependency, normally a patch version wouldn't cause an issue like that so it might be a rare issue that's difficult to find
As a temporary solution it looks you can set the lambda runtime manually and stop it from updating it so you can have some time to find the issue then update the runtime version. There is some information in the aws documentation about this:

In the rare event that a new runtime version is incompatible with your existing function, you can roll back its runtime version to an earlier one. This keeps your application working and minimizes disruption, providing time to remedy the incompatibility before returning to the latest runtime version.

I'm assuming your lambda function is currently using the $LATEST version by default, and must be automatically updating the runtime version as well, so these instructions might be what you need

If you're using the Auto runtime version update mode, or you're using the $LATEST runtime version, you can roll back your runtime version using the Manual mode. For the function version you want to roll back, change the runtime version update mode to Manual and specify the ARN of the previous runtime version.

You can get the ARN of the working version from the labda logs you posted with the question
These are documentation pages I found this info from

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-update.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-update.html#runtime-management-controls
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-update.html#runtime-management-identify


Fixing it to 18.v26 is what we did, but your statement about what their v.26 means makes sense (though does not answer how to find the Node version underneath).

yeah ok, well, maybe not the cleanest way, but you can add console.log(process.versions) into the code running in the lambda, this will log an object out to the cloudwatch logs with the node version and also other dependencies used by the node process, example in node docs: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/process.html#processversions
